# Determining whether or not a MemberExpression belongs to an instance

Tags: .net, expression-trees

I am trying to determine whether or not a `MemberExpression` belongs to an object instance or if it's just a parameter in an expression.  I came up with what I believe to be a viable solution, but I want to run this by SE first.  Take these two expressions for starters:

```
var myClassInstance = new MyClass();

Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> exp1 = mc => myClassInstance.MyBool;
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> exp2 = mc => mc.MyBool;
```

`exp1` contains a reference to a local variable/field.  Further down in my code, `.MyBool` will be compiled to retrieve its value like this:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Convert(exp1.Body as MemberExpression, typeof(object))).Compile();
```

In `exp2`, `.MyBool` is not from an object reference, but a paremeter.  If I were to try to compile the `.MyBool` expression, the exception `variable 'mc' of type 'ConsoleLol.MyClass' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined` would be thrown.

After some toil, I've come up with this potential solution:

```
var exp1parent = (exp1.Body as MemberExpression).Expression;
var exp2parent = (exp2.Body as MemberExpression).Expression;

Console.WriteLine(exp1parent.NodeType);
Console.WriteLine(exp2parent.NodeType);
```

It seems that, if the expression's parent expression is not an instance, the `NodeType` property will be `Parameter`.  Otherwise, it will be something else like, in this case, `MemberAccess`.

Am I correct in this conclusion or is there a more ideal method of performing this check?

Comment: Could you explain what are you actually trying to do? Why is the expression `Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>`, when you don't seem to have `MyClass` to pass it? Why don't you use `Expression<Func<bool>>`, which would avoid all of this?

Comment: @svick Not sure what you mean. `Func<MyClass, bool>` is defined to accept a `MyClass` as the parameter and return a `bool`.  Besides, I need `MyClass` because I am using this to convert an expression into SQL.  I need to know if the expression belongs to an instance member so that I can determine whether or not to compile it to get its value or convert the expression to a custom SQL function.  Hard to explain it all in detail with limited space

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're building an SQL provider and so you need to evaluate everything that can't be translated to SQL. An explanation of how to do that is in Matt Warren's article [Building an IQueryable Provider – Part III](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattwar/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii/) or you can use it as `PartialEvaluator` from his [iqtoolkit](https://github.com/mattwar/iqtoolkit) library.

Comment: I've already pretty much done all of that by creating a method that recurses down the expression tree.  As I said in a comment in my OP, it's difficult to explain what I am really wanting to do, but I have to know whether or not to compile a member or method or convert the member to a custom SQL expression (like convert `mc.FirstName.Length == 10` to `length(FirstName) = 10` in my SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Op here with an answer to my own question.

This may be a work in progress, but it works so far.  When walking your expression tree and trying to decide whether a property expression should be interpreted as a database field or if it should be compiled for the SQL value parameter, you need to know if the expression descends from a lambda expression parameter.  If it doesn't and you try to compile/invoke it, you will get the error mentioned in my OP.

Here's what I have for starters.  You basically just keep hopping up the expression tree until the parent expression `NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter` or the parent expression is null.  If the former, it's a parameter descendent, so don't compile it.  If the latter, it represents a database field, so parse it accordingly.

```
public static bool IsParameterDescendent(this Expression Expression)
{
    var pe = Expression;

    while (pe != null && pe.NodeType != ExpressionType.Constant)
    {
        if (pe.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            pe = pe.TryCast<MemberExpression>().Expression;
        }
        else if (pe.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
        {
            pe = pe.TryCast<MethodCallExpression>().Object;
        }

        if (pe?.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Edit:**  One way you could avoid having to do this altogether is disciplining yourself to always put the database property on the left side of the operator and the invokable/value provider on the right side.  I don't like being restricted to that, though, hence this method.